# Should we make [twitterapi] and [twittersdk] synonyms of [twitter]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

There were two new twitter related tags [twitterapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitterapi) and [twittersdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twittersdk) created recently.

Since [twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) is already a synonym of [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) should these new tags also be synonyms of [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter)? Or should the few questions in these new tags just be re-tagged?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a point in making them synonyms. They would be rarely used.

In my opinion, questions with these tags should just be retagged.