# Moderation tools / new tags | tag synonym request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonym-process

I recently breached the 10k barrier, so I thought of looking at the moderation tools page. There is a "New tags" section, and I clicked on the tag [twitterapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitterapi) and I thought, this should be a synonym for [twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) which I found out is a synonym for [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter). So I went to the [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) and tried to create a synonym. I then got the error message:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

Well... this is hawkward :p

### TL;DR:

So my question is two-pronged:

1. I would request some body to create a suggestion for the [twitterapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitterapi) to be a synonym for [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) who does have the needed points.
2. What is the use for me to see all the new tags when I can't directly act upon this information?

Comment: This happens in more places in the 10K tools: you are able to see stuff but not act on it. Those areas have some rough edges ;-)

Comment: I retagged the twitterapi question to twitter-api. Since the tag is now abandoned it should disappear around daychange IIRC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the synonym request is a duplicate of [Should we make [twitterapi] and [twittersdk] synonyms of [twitter]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335697/should-we-make-twitterapi-and-twittersdk-synonyms-of-twitter)
2. You use the new tags list so you can immediately [burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) those new tags in case they are no good. Or provide a tag wiki in case the new tag is awesome.

Can you next time please stick to one question per question?